# App icon on iPad doesn't change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4, icons

I'm trying to replace my iPad icon app on my iPad. However, for some reason the icon doesn't change and app always installed with the old icon.

I tried the following -

- didn't find anything wrong with info.plist file
- installed on iPhone & iPad simulator and also on my iPhone - works fine with the right icon
- delete app and reinstall on iPad - doesn't help
- restart the iPad - doesn't help
- clean cache - the only clean cache option I found on my iPad is related to the Safari app - tried it anyway - doesn't help.

My iPad is running with iOs 4.3.3 - icon doesn't change
My iPhone is running with iOS 5.0 - works fine
iPhone & iPad simulators 4.3 & 5.0 - works fine.

Any idea?

Many thanks for your help,

Dudi

Comment: Open your application folder where your images are saved, check if you have two separate files with icon.png in two different directory. or else close Xcode reopen it and try again, else shutdown mac restart and try again :)

Answer (score 6):

You can try some of these: restarting xcode, clean build folder, project-archive and look inside the zip, check ipad-icon in your project with finder. 
good luck.

Comment: Seems that clean build was sufficient at this time - Thanks a lot, Dudi

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting the app off of your iPad as well as running a **Clean Build** before re-installing it back on to your iPad?

Comment: Indeed running clean build resolved the problem.
Many thanks, Dudi

Answer (score 1):

Try a clean build: Product > Clean.

Particularly having deleted the app off your device, and still found this problem, the need for a clean build is by far the most likely issue.